# Is possible to getting current model information on button click in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js

I want need all information of current model on button click event in backbone js. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Derick Bailey wrote a good blog on this topic if you're using only Backbone:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/

If you use Bailey's Marionette, however, you can accomplish this functionality quite easily.

For example:

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...

  triggers: {
    "click .do-something": "do:something:button:clicked"
  }
});

view = new MyView();
view.render();

view.on("do:something:button:clicked", function(args){
  myModel = args.model  // the model is accessible here
});
```